# Can Someone Help Me Troubleshoot Error In BQ "does not contain valid backup metadata."

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep trying to upload a new table onto my companies BQ, but I keep getting the error you see in the title ("does not contain valid backup metadata.").

For reference, I'm uploading a .csv file that has been saved to our Google Cloud data storage. It's being uploaded as a native table.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you go to https://bigquery.cloud.google.com, find your table, and click on details, do the details look like this: http://i.imgur.com/ANj2e0i.png ?

Comment: If you provide a `project_id:job_id` of a failing job, we can check out what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are specifying the file type `DATASTORE_BACKUP`. When you specify that file type, BigQuery will take whatever uri you provide (even if it has a .CSV suffix) and search for the Google Cloud Data Storage Backup files relative to that url.